# How to know if a string is a regex in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am using the module `re` in Python 3.3 to work with regular expressions. Users give my program a string (supposed to be regex) and it has to work with that regex.

I think it is pretty impossible, but, is there any way to know if a string is a valid regex?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you want to use this for, but be aware that certain regular expressions can cause a denial of service; it's not wise to let users enter regular expressions which you're going to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply try to compile the regex using [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile), and an [`re.error`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.error) will be thrown if the regex is invalid.

```
try:
    re.compile(regex)
except re.error:
    # not valid
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that trying to [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) and catch errors is the most useful way, but depending on how complicated the regex can be, it could also be possible to use a regex to test if a given string is a regex...

(But I think to describe all valid Python regexes, you need at least a [context free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar))

Answer (score 0):

You can try compiling it within a try finally.  This won't catch use case when a user  accidentally makes a valid regex, but it will catch any instance when he supplies an invalid one.  You can try replacing the invalid '++' string with something valid like '[1-9]' to see it work.

```
import re

try:
    r = re.compile('++')
except:
    print 'Invalid Regex'
else:
print 'Regex valid'
```